# Why does Mathematica not know some integrals diverge?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to analyse the convergence of some complicated 1d integrals that may have divergences at $x=0$, similarly to the harmonic integral $\int_0^a 1/x \ \mathbb{d} x$, which I know is divergent.
When I try

```
Integrate[1/x,{x,0,10}]
```

Mathematica neither solves the integral, nor tell it is divergent. If I try

```
Integrate[1/x, x]
```

It gives the correct answer, $log(x)$, however when I try to numerically calculate the integral with

```
NIntegrate[1/x, {x, 0, 10}]
```

It gives no error or warning message, rather a finite result! I tried to play with PrecisionGoal but I still couldn't get any error. Is there a way for Mathematica to spot more accurately non convergent integrals? The integrals I want to analyse might suffer from the same issues and have no analytical solution, so I am afraid I might not spot the divergences.

Comment: On **MMA 13.0**: `Integrate[1/x, {x, 0, 10}]` give me: "Integral of 1/x does not converge on {0,10}". **This message is generated when the indicated definite integral does not converge.**

Comment: I have mathematica 12, maybe that's what happening?

Comment: Also in 13: NIntegrate[1/x, {x, 0, 10}] says "NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections.... " Limit[Integrate[1/x, {x, ep, 10}], ep -> 0] returns "Indeterminate".

Comment: Thanks! I updated to Mathematica 13 and now I do get these messages, so I definitely think it was an issue of Mathematica 12