# Behavior of Mathematica 12.3.1, 13.0.1 under certain integrations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-12.3, version-13, version-12.0

I have a couple of modules (Laplace transformation of Plus-distributions) that were completely straightforward to integrate with version `12.0.0`. However, recently with versions `12.3.1`, and `13.0.1` it seems not that straightforward.

Example:

```
Integrate[Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y]-1),{x,0,Infinity},GenerateConditions->False]
  (**version 12.0.0**)
(6 EulerGamma^2  + Pi^2  + 6 Log[y] (2 EulerGamma + Log[y]) )/12
```

The version `12.0.0` just spilled out the results instantly whereas on the other hand
versions `12.3.1`, and `13.0.1` does not even perform the integration.
Of course, there are different ways to perform the integration (and to implement it in the newer versions), but it is really surprising how the newer versions become worse day by day without backward compatibility for such basic features (or not that basic? at least it was nice in version `12.0.0`)!

---

Edit

I thought that Mathematica `12.0.0` is giving the correct result.
I tried to derive this in a way (not sure if this is correct though, always there are deep mathematical constraints that are not naively imaginable).

With this method, I can produce the results by Mathematica `12.0.0`.

[image]

---

Comment: Differentiation with respect to a parameter under an improper integral should be grounded. In many cases this implies incorrect results. See [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Parameter-dependent_integral) for info.

Comment: I agree with you that this is a gray area. But I believe this integral exists. Let me look up some literature.

Comment: Is this used in QCD?

Comment: Yes. I know mathematicians don’t like this but is used widely in QCD. I also use this but this is the only proof I convinced myself. I could not find any math book to refer this.

Comment: Looks like this is cool new functionality. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/268207/why-does-mathematica-not-know-some-integrals-diverge and of course we like this but we need a type of Regularization for this https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269178/an-unclear-mathematica-result-for-borel-summation/269207#269207.

Answer (score 6):

This integral does not converge. Here's one way to confirm this:

```
f[a_,y_]=Integrate[Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y]-1),{x,0,a},Assumptions->{a>0,y>0}];
Limit[f[a,y],a->∞,Assumptions->y>0]
```

Gives $-\infty$

Here's another way

```
f[x_, y_] = Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y] - 1);
AsymptoticIntegrate[f[x, y], x, x -> ∞, 
 Assumptions -> y > 0]
```

gives $-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(x)$ which is divergent as $x\to\infty$

Mathematica `12.0.0` was wrong, the newer versions are giving you the correct result.

Comment: Your `AsymptoticIntegrate` is interesting. If I remove the `Assumptions` I get `-((E^(-x y) Log[x])/(x y)) + 
 1/12 (6 EulerGamma^2 + \[Pi]^2 - 12 EulerGamma Log[x] + 
    12 EulerGamma Log[x y] - 12 Log[x] Log[x y] + 6 Log[x y]^2)`

Comment: This has a finite part exactly what is found in 12.0.

Comment: @Boogeyman: An then `Limit[1/12 (6 EulerGamma^2+\[Pi]^2-12 EulerGamma Log[x]+12 EulerGamma Log[x y]-12 Log[x] Log[x y]+6 Log[x y]^2),x->Infinity]` results in `-Infinity` and `Limit[-((E^(-x y) Log[x])/(x y)),x->Infinity]` results in `ConditionalExpression[0, y > 0]`.

Comment: I would have restricted `0<y<Infinity` looking at my claim of the final answer. But let me think about what `AsymptoticIntegrate` does with other examples of the related kind.

Comment: @Boogeyman if $y<0$ this integral is trivially divergent since $e^{-xy}$ blows up as $x$ grows. Note also that the expression you get contains terms like $\log(xy)$ which are imaginary when $y<0$

Comment: A related example `g[x_,y_] = (Exp[-x y] - Exp[-x])/x Log[x];`  gives `((E^-x - E^(-x y)/y) Log[x])/x + 1/2 Log[y] (2 EulerGamma + Log[y])`  which is fine as `x->Infinity` as long as `y>0`.  This gives correct textbook result `1/2 Log[y] (2 EulerGamma + Log[y])` from Lewin 1981, eq, 1.106. My example is little worse though.

Comment: A similar second example  `f[x_,y_]=1/x (Exp[-x*y]-1);`  With `Integrate[f[x,y],{x,0,\[Infinity]},GenerateConditions->False]`  Mathematica gives `-EulerGamma - Log[y]`. The procedure given in the question reproduces it. `AsymptoticIntegrate` causes similar problem i.e. not convergent. Although one could argue that `GenerateConditions -> False` should be removed! :(

Comment: @Boogeyman The first example works since $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\log(x)/x \ dx$ converges. The 2nd example indeed doesn't work. It's not a `GenerateConditions` thing, the integral actually doesn't converge. Try it out yourself. Pick a $y$ value, say $y=2$ and do `Table[NIntegrate[f[x, 2], {x, 0, 10^n}], {n, 2, 10}]`. Without `GenerateConditions` Mathematica says this is $-\gamma -\log (2)\approx -1.27$. The `NIntegrate` should clearly convince you that's wrong...

Comment: @bRost03 Can the Table[] hack be done for the OP integral?

Answer (score 1):

The Integral with 13.0.1 gives

```
Integrate[x^(a - 1)*Log[x]*(Exp[(-x)*y] - 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* ConditionalExpression[(Gamma[a]*(-Log[y]+PolyGamma[0,a]))/y^a,
   -1 < Re[a] < 0 && Re[y] > 0 && Im[y] == 0] *)
```

with condition among others that -1<a<0. This is supported by numeric calculation:

```
y = 7/10;Show[ListPlot[Table[{a, 
NIntegrate[x^(a - 1)*Log[x]*(Exp[(-x)*y] - 1), {x, 0, 10^100}, 
Method -> "DoubleExponential"]}, {a, -0.99, 0, 0.01}]], 
Plot[(Gamma[a]*(-Log[y] + PolyGamma[0, a]))/y^a, 
  {a, -0.99, 0}, PlotStyle -> {Orange}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

where you see that the integral seems to diverge for a->0 and not have a small value like

```
(6 EulerGamma^2 + Pi^2 + 6 Log[y] (2 EulerGamma + Log[y]))/12
       (* 4.005549 for y=0.7 *)
```

If the numerical integral is done with upper limit Infinity there is better agreement near a=-1, but this is probably because then also symbolic processing is used by Mathematica. The Method DoubleExponential gives the best agreement here with large but finite upper limit.

Comment: Then the question is after your comparison plot if one can compare coefficients of ‘a’ which is finite and corresponds to the original integral.

Comment: Btw I see that you have started with a different integration and then taking a->0.

Comment: I agree that your integral is divergent. This can be also seen by just expanding your result around `a=0`. My question: whether a series expansion is permissible on both sides. If yes, then it would be an infinite sum of finite terms/integrals. One of which would be the integrand in the question. In some way, the divergence will be regulated with `1/a` kind of term.

Answer (score -1):

In version 13 on Windows 10:

```
Series[Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y] - 1), {x, Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> x > 0 && y > 0] // Normal
```

> $\frac{e^{-x y} \log (x)}{x}-\frac{\log (x)}{x}$

shows the integral under consideration diverges at infinity so the result in version 12 is not correct. Version 13 reports the divergence when executing `Integrate[Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y] - 1), {x, 0, Infinity},  GenerateConditions -> True]`.

Comment: Well, not really! This is a finite integral (plus-distribution). Mathematica 12.0.0 is giving the correct result. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2665891/solving-an-integral-including-a-plus-distribution

Comment: Sorry, this link is not math, but science fiction.

Comment: Sorry, this link might be science fiction. But this integral is doable and finite. One approach would be to start with a different integrand like `x^(-1+a) (Exp[-y x] -1)`   and do a derivative wrt `y`. With this, the RHS will become simpler integration. Then one needs to series expand both sides (after `y` integration as well) in `a` and from the coefficient you will see that the coefficient of `a` term will lead to this integrand with the result stated in the question which is also correctly produced by Mathematica12.0.0. The integrand is logarithmically divergent but integrable.

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing to discuss with you  in such manner.

Comment: I am not sure whether I upset you or you just don't want to chat or you believe my claim is wrong. Somehow I do not find clarity in your current answer. And I also tried to provide a derivation (see edit) if that is what you meant. Nevertheless thanks for engaging.

Comment: So, version 13 is wrong, should generate conditions.

Comment: `Series` here did nothing, that's literally the function in question? Not sure what that was supposed to show? I agree it diverges but I fail to see how it follows from what you've shown. Sorry if I'm being dense...

Comment: @bRost03: You are not right. The result of `Series` together with the divergence of the integral $\int_1^\infty -\frac {\log x} x \,dx$ imply the divergence of the integral under consideration. In fact, `AsymptoticIntegrate` realises that approach. I also  used `Series` to verify the convergence at the origin.

Comment: @user64494 what did I say that was not right? The only claim I made was that `Series` did nothing here. That's obviously true. Just see `Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y] - 1) == Series[Log[x]/x (Exp[-x*y] - 1), {x,Infinity, 2}, Assumptions -> x > 0 && y > 0] // Normal // Expand` returns `True`. The rest was just my confusion about how your conclusion followed from what you showed.

Comment: @bRost03: You are not right.  I explain it in other words. The result of `Series` shows that the integrand is equivalent to $-\frac {\log x} x$ as $x\to\infty$. Since the improper integral $\int_1^\infty -\frac {\log x} x \,dx$ diverges, this implies the divergence of the integral under consideration. Hope I am clear. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: @user64494 Do you disagree that for our case of $f(x,y)=(e^{-xy}-1)\log(x)/x$ that `Normal@Series[f[x,y],{x,Infinity,2}]==f[x,y]`? That's literally all I am saying. You can confirm it in 2 seconds on your own machine. `Series` does *nothing* to this function.

Comment: @user64494 in a separate thread, your conclusion is correct but your logic is sloppy. Yes $\int_1^{\infty} \log(x)/x \ dx$ diverges but so does $\int_0^1 \log(x)e^{-xy}/x \ dx$ and $\int_0^1 \log(x)/x \ dx$ so you have to show that these divergences don't cancel out to reach your conclusion. They don't indeed cancel, and the final integral is divergent, but you at least have to check.

Comment: @bRost03:  Please be correct:   "your logic is sloppy"  does not make a good impression. The integral $\int_1^{\infty} \log(x)/x \ dx$ diverges at infinity so  $\int_0^1 \log(x)e^{-xy}/x \ dx$ and $\int_0^1 \log(x)/x \ dx$ are not necessary to consder.

Comment: Tone notwithstanding, this does show the divergence (once you recognize that the two terms are not comparable in that one converges while the other does not).